# Infinite product$\prod _{k=0}^{\infty } \left(1-q^{3\ 2^k}\right)^{-2^{-k-1}} \left(q^{3\ 2^k}+1\right)^{2^{-k-1}}=\frac{1}{q^3-1}$

Tags: calculus

I have seen in a forum the following infinite product $$\prod _{k=0}^{\infty } \left(q^{2^k}+1\right)=\frac{1}{1-q}$$ q<1 and How was it obtained and the product of the title could it be correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

In order to obtain the proposed relation, multiply and divide the LHS by $q - 1$ then take the limit.

**EDIT**

Consider the product:
\begin{align*}
\prod_{k=0}^{n}(q^{2^{k}} + 1) = (q + 1)(q^{2} + 1)(q^{4} + 1)\ldots(q^{2^{n}} + 1)
\end{align*}

If we multiply it and divide it by $q - 1$, it results that
\begin{align*}
\frac{q - 1}{q - 1}\prod_{k=0}^{n}(q^{2^{k}} + 1) & = \frac{(q - 1)(q + 1)(q^{2} + 1)\ldots(q^{2^{n}} + 1)}{q - 1}\\\\
& = \frac{(q^{2} - 1)(q^{2} + 1)(q^{4} + 1)\ldots(q^{2^{n}} + 1)}{q - 1}\\\\
& = \frac{(q^{4} - 1)(q^{4} + 1)(q^{8} + 1)\ldots(q^{2^{n}} + 1)}{q - 1}\\\\
& = \ldots = \frac{q^{2^{n + 1}} - 1}{q - 1}
\end{align*}

Since $|q| < 1$, we can take the limit in the expression above to obtain that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{k=0}^{n}(q^{2^{k}} + 1) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{q^{2^{n+1}} - 1}{q - 1} = -\frac{1}{q - 1} = \frac{1}{1 - q}
\end{align*}

Comment: I did not understand the answer very well. Are you referring to the formula of the question or the formula of the title? Could you be more specific, and in any case it would not be a demonstration

Comment: @Capeamate I am referring to the formula of the question. I have edited my answer in order to provide a full explanation.